# Verifying Green's theorem for a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, gaussian-integral, greens-theorem

Let

$G = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+4y^2 >1, x^2+y^2 < 4 \} $

$ \int_G x^2+y^2 d(x,y) $

I want to verify Green's Theorem :
$ \oint_{ \partial G } f n ds = \int_G \operatorname{div}f\, dx $

I solved for he righthand side:

$ \int_G \operatorname{div}f dx = \frac{25}{32} \pi $,

just by calculating the Integral for the circle and the ellipse separately and subtract.

For the lefthand side, I need to find $ f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2} $ so that $ \operatorname{div}f = x^2+y^2 $
that can be $ f=( \frac{1}{3} x^3 , \frac{1}{3} y^3 ) $

now my question is, how to proceed? :0
Do I have to split the region? 
Is $ n=  \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ (\frac{1}{3} x^3 )^2+ ( \frac{1}{3}y^3 )^2}} \begin{pmatrix}  \frac{1}{3} x^3 \\ \frac{1}{3} y^3 \end{pmatrix} $ ?

Looking forward to any help! :-)

Comment: Is $x^2+y^2$ already the divergence, or are you getting the divergence from that some how?

Comment: yes, it is $ div f = x^2+y^2 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf r$ is not normal to the ellipse. If the boundary is parametrized as $\mathbf r(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, then $\mathbf n(t) = (y'(t), -x'(t))$ is normal to the boundary and
$$\int_{\partial D} \mathbf F \cdot \frac {\mathbf n} {|\mathbf n|} \,ds =
\int_a^b \mathbf F \cdot \frac {\mathbf n} {|\mathbf n|} \,|\mathbf r'| \,dt =
\int_a^b \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf n \,dt.$$
We have $\mathbf F = (x^3/3, y^3/3), \,\mathbf r_1(t) = (\cos t, 1/2 \sin t), \,\mathbf r_2(t) = (2 \cos t, 2 \sin t)$, thus
$$\begin{aligned}
&\begin{aligned}
\int_{\partial D} \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf n \,dt =
&\int_0^{2 \pi} \left( \frac {\cos^3 t} 3, \frac {\sin^3 t} {24} \right) \cdot
 \left( -\frac {\cos t} 2, -\sin t \right) dt + {} \\
&\int_0^{2 \pi} \left( \frac {8 \cos^3 t} 3, \frac {8 \sin^3 t} {3} \right) \cdot
 (2 \cos t, 2 \sin t) \,dt,
\end{aligned} \\
&\int_D \nabla \cdot \mathbf F \,dS =
\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_{1/\sqrt{\cos^2 t + 4 \sin^2 t}}^2 \,r^3 dr dt.
\end{aligned}$$
Both are equal to $251 \pi/32$.

Answer (score 0):

$f=x^2+y^2=r^2=f=\nabla \cdot (r^3/4 \hat{r})$

So $\vec{F}=\frac{r^3}{4}\hat{r}$

The normal to a "surface" in 2d is the unit vector perpendicular to the tangent line.

The curves here can be parameterized as

$x=a\cos{\theta}$

$y=b\sin{\theta}$

Where for the ellipse $a=1$, $b=1/2$. For the circle $a=b=2$

The tangent line vector is $-a\sin{\theta}\hat{i}+b\cos{\theta}\hat{j}$

So the normal line vector is $b\cos{\theta}\hat{i}+a\sin{\theta}\vec{j}$

So the unit normal

$\hat{n}= \frac{<b\cos{\theta}, a\sin{\theta}>}{\sqrt{b^2\cos^2{\theta}+a^2\sin^2{\theta}}}$

$\vec{r}=<a\cos{\theta}, b\sin{\theta}>$

So $\vec{F}\cdot \hat{n}dA =\frac{r^2}{4}\frac{ab}{\sqrt{b^2\cos^2{\theta}+a^2\sin^2{\theta}}} d\theta $

You probably want to run that integral clockwise around the ellipse and counter clockwise around the circle. Integrate from 0 to $2\pi$

Comment: The norm of $n$ doesn't contain an $a b$ term.

Comment: Correct. I took r from r^3 and multiplied it with $\hat{r}$, then dotted that with $\hat{n}$ producing the result.

Comment: I'm saying that if $\mathbf n = (b \cos \theta, a \sin \theta)$, then $|\mathbf n| = \sqrt{b^2 \cos^2 \theta + a^2 \sin^2 \theta}$. Also, the divergence of $r^3/3 \,\hat {\mathbf r}$ is not $r^2$, it's $4 r^2/3$. And what is $dA$? Area element?

Comment: $\nabla \cdot \vec{A}$ in cylindrical coordinates = $\frac{\partial A_r}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial A_\theta}{r\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial z}$

$\vec{F}=r^3/3\hat{r}$  So: $\nabla \cdot \vec{F}=\frac{\partial(r^3/3)}{\partial r}$

$\nabla \cdot \vec{F}=r^2$

Comment: I asee what you mean about the norm. Corrected! Thanks!

Comment: i messed up the r term: $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(rA_r)=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^4/3)$ Going to correct that too. '